# numpy.where on structured array with object dtype of tuples

Tags: arrays, object, numpy, tuples, where-clause

```
import numpy as np
rec=np.recarray((10,),names=('x'),formats=('object'))
for i in rec:
    i.x=(0,0)
print np.where(rec.x==(0,0))
```

The result is `(array([], dtype=int32),)`, not 0 to 9 that I expected. why? Can anybody explain for me and how should I get the index of this kind of structured array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More efficient would be:

```
rec = np.zeros(10, [('x', [('a', int), ('b', int)] )] )
```

This way you're storing a compact representation in memory, can you can compare elements:

```
rec == rec[0]
```

Note that searching for double-zeros is still slightly tricky, but you can do it generically:

```
rec == np.zeros(1, rec.dtype)
```

If you don't need a single `x` which refers to the pair you could remove that level of the record structure:

```
rec = np.zeros(10, [('x0', int), ('x1', int)])
```

Or simplest of all:

```
rec = np.zeros(10, [('x', '2i')])
```

The comparisons will work the same in any case.

Comment: Thanks! I think I went to the wrong direction. But why it returns empty array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking now.